# Мне нужно вывести число, которое заканчивается к примеру на 2. Что не так с моим кодом?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n=int(input())
n%10==2
print(n)
```

Comment: Вы число вводите. Запрашиваете с клавиатуры.

Answer (score 4):

```
n = int(input())
if n % 10 == 2:
    print(n)
```

Comment: @S.Nick В чем смысл вашей правки?

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(input()) 
if n%10==2:
    print (n)
```

Comment: Чем отличается от существующего ответа?

Comment: @Suvitruf, тем, что вполне игнорирован PEP 8.